# Cell reference calculation within a range formula

Tags: excel, formulas

I am using this formula to search a range of cells for the letters "cc".
=COUNTIF(G4:G28,"cc")*G3

This lets us know who paid with a credit card. I was told that we also need to know the date. So now I am adding the date to the cell using this format "cc (10/03)" Of course now the formula does not count this cell because the formula is looking for "cc" only. So now I need to replace the "cc" part of the formula with something that looks in the cell for "cc". I think I can use ISNUMBER but that requires that I enter a specific cell in the formula. Since this formula is being used as part of a formula that contains a range, how would I do this?

Hope this makes sense.

Many thanks,
Houston

Answer (score 2):

If you need to have the date in the same cell then you can use a "wildcard" * in `COUNTIF` like this

`=COUNTIF(G4:G28,"cc*")*G3`

then that will count all cells that start with "cc"....or a wildcard either side if you need, i.e.

`=COUNTIF(G4:G28,"*cc*")*G3`

which would count cells that contain "cc" anywhere.

Ideally you would put the date in a separate cell in the same row so that your original formula would still function OK